# CI Gitlab fails with docker daemon system failure

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab CI pipeline setup and sometimes I get random failures where the test is on-going but then it shows:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

What could be the reason for this?

This is on Gitlab  11.1.4, gitlab-runner 10.7.4, Docker version 1.13.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be a too old docker daemon. Recent docker versions >= 18.06.0-ce seem to behave well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

So a docker container cannot be created.

It could be those Reasons:

```
- the user gitlab-runner (the one who take the pipelines and starts them) is not member of the docker group

    - sudo usermod -a -G docker gitlab-runner

- The Daemon is not running. Enable it (so that it start at boot)

     systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
```

Comment: That unfortunately is not the problem. I run things regularly without problems but every so often I get the error above as if the docker daemon crashes and then is restarted automatically.